# How to do many-to-many pub sub relation

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system, pyzmq, multi-agent, pgm-protocol

I have seen it mentioned that ZMQ supports a many-to-many PUB/SUB relation.

In this case what I would like is to have multiple subscribers to multiple publishers, (this is for a common bus style application), however what I am confused about is how to physically implement it since I have also seen it mentioned that there can only be a single bind and multiple connections to that bound socket.

Thus I am slightly confused as to how to achieve this.

I have seen that pgm may be a way to acheive this (since all members would connect to the same multicast address), but I am not sure how to physically do that...

Comment: "physically"!? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *how to physically implement it*

A `PUB_A` on a Computer A **`PUB_A.bind()`**-s, any `SUB` may `.connect()` there, onto A

A `PUB_B` on a Computer B **`PUB_B.bind()`**-s, any `SUB` may `.connect()` there, onto B

A `rev_PUB_C` on any host **`rev_PUB_C.connect()`**-s to a few or many `SUB`-s, who've had a previously successful **`SUB_xyz.bind()`** onto their respective local address(es)

And the merry-go-round goes on, as the distributed system designer likes it to let the show evolve.

Comment: So literally just call connect from a subscriber to on each of the publishers addresses?

Comment: **Roger, exactly that** [ or may similarly let, with legal and mirrored setup & fully functional result, let some `SUB`-s do also their own **`.bind()`** and also let all the respective `PUB`-s **`.connect()`** to This Herd of { Normal | Reversed | Dual-Mode } `SUB`-s ] ...... that's cool either :o)